# What is the difference between a Google Cloud "app" and a "project"?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How does an app interact with a project?

Aren't both required?

Why would I want to create one but not the other?

Is a project superior to an app? or vice versa?

Why is a project part of a configuration but not an app?

Here is some code in reference to my question:

```
gcloud app create --region=us-west3 --project=jddjango-tutorial 
gcloud projects create cx-0705-1 --name="JD cx test"
```

Comment: To which kind of "app" are you talking? A mobile app? An app in app engine? Please add more details and be more clear. So far the question seems to be off-topic

Comment: Ferregina, I've updated w/ more detail, thank you.

Comment: What you are creating is an app in App Engine. Most of your questions can be answered by reading the documentation so I'd suggest to first read the docs and understand what you're using https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs

Comment: I'm answering this in the commments because the complete questions are not about programming which is what SO is intended for:

1. How does an app interact with a project? A project contains an app
2. Aren't both required? No, you can have a project without an app
3. Why would I want to create one but not the other? None of them are similar things. Please first understand the usage of App Engine
4. Is a project superior to an app? Both are complete different things, nevertheless a project contains an app
5. Why is a project part of a configuration but not an app? This is not clear

Comment: P.D. What you say is "some code" are actually commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/projects)

   > A project organizes all your Google Cloud resources. A project consists of a set of users; a set of APIs; and billing, authentication, and monitoring settings for those APIs.
2. This other [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects) also has a similar explanation

   > Google Cloud projects form the basis for creating, enabling, and using all Google Cloud services including managing APIs, enabling billing, adding and removing collaborators, and managing permissions for Google Cloud resources.
3. An App is a 'resource' or a 'service'. A project can have multiple Apps e.g. you can have a Cloud Run App, App Engine App, Compute Engine App under the same Project.
4. You can think of it from the POV of

   a. A project is the root/parent node. You must create one to use any google resource/service. You also create billing for the project.

   b. Under a project, you can then create an App. When you create an App, you specify the region (refer to your example command of `gcloud app create --region=us-west3`)